# "this" keyword in javascript(as instance)

Tags: javascript, this, instance

AFAIK "this" is used when there is clash between "property" & "parameter" of function.
Please find my code below.

```
<script>
    function person(firstName, lastName, age, eyeColor) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.fullName = function() {
            return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname
        }
    }
    var p = new person();
    document.write("fullname is " + p.fullName());
</script>
```

Here please correct me if I am wrong with following things

> this.firstName contains "this" because person contains firstName as    parameter and wants to be as property of person.
>   My **doubt is that**
>   this.fullName also has "this" in it even thought there is  no parameter with fullName.May be I am wrong(Read that **"this" actually creates an instance**).
>   If above is true that it actually creates an instance 
>    then **my problem** is
>   it is creating instance in var `p = new person()` and why would we create instance of `fullName` property  inside of person

Comment: Possibly related: [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript) If I'm perhaps following your question, it isn't necessary to set `fullName` within `person`. It can be set on `person.prototype` and apply to all instances of `person`.

Comment: Hint: JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: just a question, shouldn't the parameters be set when creating an instance of person? like: `var p = new person('foo,'bar');`  http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/sLoqumz2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

1. this.firstname contains "this" because person contains firstname as parameter and wants to be as property of person.  - **wrong**

`this` is used to assign any value to the property of the object (instance of Person class)

`this.firstName = your_var` this will assign value of `your_var` to `firstName` property of `Person`'s object it doesn't matter if your_var is in parameters or some local var created by you 
You can assign any value to property of an object

2. Read that "this" actually creates an instance - **wrong**

`this` refers to the created instance and does not create instance

3. you are not creating instance full name here, what you are doing is creating an instance method for person object which you can later on use to get full name of the person

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice if you run this code you get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: p.fullname is not a function on line 10
```

There is an error in the capitalization of your method call.
Corrected code is below:

```
document.write("fullname is " + p.fullName());
```

Answer (score 0):

your properties are like `fooBar` and you are returning them as `foobar`,  these places:

```
this.firstName = firstName; // firstName
this.lastName = lastName; // lastName
//but below as firstname, lastname instead of firstName and lastName
return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname
```

also on here:

```
    this.fullName = function(){ ... }
```

but you call the function as `p.fullname()`

---

Also I think, since the `fullName()` returns `firstName` and `lastName`, you *probebly* need to pass these values when creating the instance if you are going to call the `fullName()` because this function requires them, otherwise you'd get `undefined`, like below:

```
var p = new person('Foo', 'Bar');
```

---

Now it is working: [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/5hLqvjfL/)

```js
function person(firstName, lastName, age, eyeColor) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.fullName = function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
  }
}
var p = new person('Foo', 'Bar');
// check the console
console.log("fullname is " + p.fullName());
```